# Based on a variable: SQL Query to fetch data for multiple values from one column OR get all values from that column

Tags: sql-server

Problem Statement :

1. when `@a` has a single word(Ex. `'name1'`) OR comma separated string (Example `'name1,name2,name3'`) then the query should return the manager names of employees with `name1 and name2 and name3`
2. when `@a` has an empty string then return the manager names of all the employees in the `emp_master` table

I have defined a stored procedure where I pass a variable.

This variable can be a comma separated string, a single word or an empty string.

If the string is comma separated then I split that string and get values based on the return table of split statement
else 
I get the related value of the non comma separated data using normal subquery

I have tried to achieve this in the following way

```
Declare @a varchar(50)= ''
select emp.Name from 
emp_master emp
where 
(LEN(@a)=0 AND emp.Name in
 (
        SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM 
        [dbo].[Emp_Master] WHERE [EmpId] IN 
        (
            SELECT 
            DISTINCT [MGR_ID] 
            FROM [dbo].[Emp_Master]
        )
    )
)
OR 
emp.Name in (Select * from [dbo].[SplitString](@a, ','))
```

Details for the above sample:

1. [dbo].[SplitString] - custom written function : returns a table of split values. So

   Select * from [dbo].SplitString

will return

```
SplitTable
----------
name1
name2
name3
```

and

```
Select * from [dbo].[SplitString](',','name1')
```

will return

```
SplitTable
----------
name1
```

2. [dbo].[Emp_Master] contains data for all the employees
3. [MGR_ID] is the column which has the employeeID of the employee manager
4. @a is the input variable
5. The Database is MS SQL 2008

My current solution(the above insane query) solves my purpose but it is very slow, it would be helpful to get an optimized and faster working solution for the problem

- Emp_master Table has 400 000 rows, 30 columns
- There are 18 000 managers in that table

Comment: shaik your code is slow for possible three reasons:
(1) PARAMETER SNIFFING
(2) SCALAR FUNCTION in WHERE condition
(3) POOR INDEXING

Comment: When @a has comma separated string then how much long it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.Emp_Master ([MGR_ID])
GO 

DECLARE @a VARCHAR(50) = '' 

DECLARE @t TABLE (val VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON))
INSERT INTO @t
SELECT item = t.c.value('.', 'INT') 
FROM (
    SELECT txml = CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(@a, ',', '</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)
) r
CROSS APPLY txml.nodes('/r') t(c)

SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ [Name]
FROM dbo.Emp_Master e1
WHERE (
            @a = ''
        AND
            e1.[EmpId] IN (SELECT DISTINCT MGR_ID FROM dbo.Emp_Master)
    )
    OR (
            @a != ''
        AND
            e.Name IN (SELECT * FROM @t)
       )
OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: The MGR_ID was a varchar type, hence just changed the INT to NVARCHAR(MAX) and it reduced the time from 7 seconds to 1 second, Fast enough for my task.
Using XML type was really amazing, saved lot of time there
Thanks @Devart you are a genius.

Comment: Sure, added these two in my TO LEARN list, thanks again @Devart

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MGR_ID_Emp_Master   ON dbo.Emp_Master ([MGR_ID])
GO 




Create Procedure searchname (@a varchar(255))
as
IF (@a = '')
BEGIN
EXEC Searchname1 @a
END
ELSE
BEGIN
EXEC Searchname2 @a 
END
```

GO

```
Create Procedure Searchname1 (@a varchar(255))
AS
 SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM 
        [dbo].[Emp_Master] m1 WHERE 
        exists


        (
            SELECT 
            *  
            FROM [dbo].[Emp_Master] m2
            WHERE 
            m1.[EmpId]= m2.[MGR_ID] 
            )
```

GO

```
Create Procedure Searchname2 (@a varchar(max)) 
AS




Select @a = ' SELECT  '''+replace( @a,',','''  Union ALL SELECT   ''')+'  '''

Create table #names (name varchar(255))
insert into #names
EXEC ( @a )


select emp.Name from 
emp_master emp
WHERE
emp.Name in( Select name FRom #names)
option (recompile)
```

> IF YOU ARE ALREADY DEALING WITH **SQL INJECTION** AT APPLICATION LEVEL
>   THEN

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Searchname2] (@a varchar(max)) 
AS





select  @a  = ''''+replace ( @a,',',''',''')+''''
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
select distinct emp.Name from 
emp_master emp
WHERE
emp.Name in( '+@a+')'


EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Creating temp tables might increase the DB load when 10000 users are working on the same page, wont it?